# Windows Batch - find & edit lines in txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for a simple script that will search a text file (input.txt) with numbers listed as such:

I have basically no experience with batch coding (or any code for the matter) and am hoping someone here can assist me.

```
0001
0002
0003
etc
```

I need the output (output.txt) to be:

```
[test]0001[/test]
[test]0002[/test] 
[test]0003[/test] 
etc
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Someone posted a python script and then deleted it before I could test it and reply. I know it's not what I originally asked for but it works great! Thank you!

This is it if someone finds this thread and can use it:

```
    rf = open("input.txt", 'r')
lines = rf.read().splitlines()
formatted_lines = ['[test]{}[/test]'.format(i) for i in lines]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for l in formatted_lines:
        wf.write("{}\n".format(l))
```

Comment: `@(for /f "delims=" %%A in (input.txt) do @Echo [test]%%A[/test])>output.txt`

Comment: Hey @jamb42, have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to transform the data from Windows Command Prompt:

```
powershell -c "cat input.txt | %{\"[test]$_[/test]\"} > output.txt"
```

Alternatively, if you can run it straight from a PowerShell, that would be:

```
cat test.txt | %{"[test]$_[/test]"} > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy and could be easily done with:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (input.txt) do echo [test]%%A[/test]
pause>nul & exit /b 0
```

This, will just `echo` the result in the console. For saving it into a file, use:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (input.txt) do (echo [test]%%A[/test])>>output.txt
pause>nul & exit /b 0
```

For `echo`ing it and save it also in a file, use:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (input.txt) do (
    echo [test]%%A[/test]
    (echo [test]%%A[/test])>>output.txt
)

pause>nul & exit /b 0
```

*Note: The same **about** solution was proposed by LotPings in comments. It is adapted not to send the output of the whole `for` loop but of the `echo` command, producing the same result.*

Comment: Enclosing the whole for has the advantage you'll not to have to clear the output file initially otherwise appending on successive runs will grow with duplicate entries.